# To support decoding 'mp3' audio files, please install 'sox'

Tags: python, pytorch, sox, soundfile, torchaudio

I'm trying to work on an ASR model using transfer learning on wav2vec 2 model.
Anyway when I ever I wan't to show or modifiy an audio file I get this problem

```
def prepare_dataset(batch):
    audio = batch["audio"]

    # batched output is "un-batched"
    batch["input_values"] = processor(audio["array"], sampling_rate=audio["sampling_rate"]).input_values[0]
    batch["input_length"] = len(batch["input_values"])
    
    with processor.as_target_processor():
        batch["labels"] = processor(batch["sentence"]).input_ids
    return batch
```

```
common_voice_train = common_voice_train.map(prepare_dataset, remove_columns=common_voice_train.column_names)
common_voice_test = common_voice_test.map(prepare_dataset, remove_columns=common_voice_test.column_names)
```

The erorrs:

> RuntimeError: Backend "sox_io" is not one of available backends: ['soundfile'].
> ImportError: To support decoding 'mp3' audio files, please install 'sox'.

This is my pytorch and torchaudio versions:

```
import torch
import torchaudio

print(torch.__version__)
print(torchaudio.__version__)
```

```
1.13.1+cu117
0.13.1+cu117
```

I really need help fixing this problem, this is part of my junior project! )':

I've trying to installing pytorch and installing deffrent versions but nothing worked the code is working. fine in colab but it's impossible for me to train it there so I have to use visual code...

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? If Linux which one (Ubuntu, Fedora, etc)? Did you install python-sox with `pip install sox`?

Comment: I'm on windows
Yes, I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TorchAudio v2.1- (Added on 2023 September)

In TorchAudio v2.1, the sox binding is switched to dynamic. Meaning that users need to install libsox separately somehow, and one way is `pip install sox`.

### Before TorchAudio v2.1 (the original answer)

First, note that the second error message is not from torchaudio and it's not accurate. TorchAudio does not depend on an external `sox` package.

TorchAudio provides limited IO features on Windows, as libsox does not
compile on Windows with VS2019. This situation is being worked on, but as of v0.13, Windows users need a workaround.

A simple way is to use other libraries like soundfile and convert the decoded NumPy NdArray object into PyTorch Tensor.

Another way is to install FFmpeg, and use `torchaudio.io.StreamReader`. You can write your own load function, following the tutorial like this.

https://pytorch.org/audio/0.13.1/tutorials/streamreader_basic_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-streamreader-basic-tutorial-py

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer!
i'll try using the solution you gave me, hopefully they're not hard to do because I'm a newbie at this.
I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue do following:

**Install normal `sox` library**

```
pip install sox
```

or (change `dnf` if you are not on fedora/rhel to `apt` for example on ubuntu)

```
sudo dnf install sox
```

**If this does not help, it is possible you still need to install the development binary of SoX.**

```
sudo dnf install sox-devel
```

[For TorchAudio to work it needs to find libsox.so in your libraries](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/installation.html#:%7E:text=torchaudio%20looks%20for%20a%20library%20file%20with%20unversioned%20name%2C%20that%20is%20libsox.so%20for%20linux) (TorchAudio >= 2.1.0).

You can check where the libsox.so is using

```
find / -name libsox.so 2>/dev/null
```